# How to make journal mode to WAL in IOS 6.0 with UIManagedDocument

Tags: ios, core-data, uimanageddocument

I am using UIManagedDocument in my Core Data, and I want to use journal mode to WAL in IOS 6.0...
how to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

The journal mode is a persistent store option when you create the `UIManagedDocument`. You would do something like:

```
UIManagedDocument *doc = [[UIManagedDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:docURL];
NSDictionary *options = @{ NSSQLitePragmasOption : @{ @"journal_mode": @"DELETE" } };
doc.persistentStoreOptions = options;
```

Also include whatever other options you use-- `NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption`, for example.